# Asp.net MVC 3 partial view postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to mvc and I have a question
I have a page (asp.net Mvc 3) called profile which contains 3 partial view called (1) Address,Qualification,Experience.
Each of the partial view should allow you to add its details and save it details/contents without affecting the others.
How can I attach an action to each partial view save button and postback the result without refreshing other partial view.

Can someone explain this to me with and without using jquery/ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without ajax or jquery you'd be stuck with doing something horrible like iFrames... Stick to jquery, it is the best and easiest way.

Actually, here is one way you might be able to do it.

Name the "Submit" buttons according to the method you want called.  Then, have all of your 3 sets of data inputs within one `<form></form>` which posts to an intermediate Controller endpoint.

In the intermediate controller endpoint, determine which button was pressed, then pass the correct data to your normal control methods, and push all the other data back to the view.  That way you can fill out all the inputs, click the appropriate submit button, then only the correct data gets used!  Then all the other data gets pushed back to the view and the approprate input boxes get filled out.